# Iterate Rows in T-SQL

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I try to calculate the difference between two date's in SQL Server. The `startdate` is, if "Interrupt" = 1 and "Automatic" = 0. The `enddate` is the next date, where "Interrupt" = 0  and "Automatic" = 1. I try to use the function

```
DATEDIFF(startdate, enddate, ...)
```

For example I have the following data:

```
ID   Date                      Interrupt    Automatic
-------------------------------------------------------
15   2020-07-06 09:56:35.630        0           1
14   2020-07-06 09:56:35.630        1           0
13   2020-07-06 09:56:33.407        1           1
12   2020-07-06 09:56:32.490        1           0
11   2020-07-06 09:56:30.073        0           1
10   2020-07-06 09:56:30.073        1           1
 9   2020-07-06 09:56:29.070        1           1
 8   2020-07-06 09:56:26.867        1           1
 7   2020-07-06 09:56:26.867        1           0
 6   2020-07-06 09:56:25.863        0           1
 5   2020-07-06 09:56:23.897        1           0
 4   2020-07-06 09:56:23.500        1           1
 3   2020-07-06 09:56:19.340        1           0
 2   2020-07-06 09:56:17.003        0           1
 1   2020-07-06 09:56:16.220        1           1
```

In this example I want to calculate the difference between the row with the ID 3 and the row with ID 6 --> DATEDIFF(ID3.Date, ID6.Date, Milliseconds)

Next case in this example, the difference between the dates of ID 11 and ID 7 --> DATEDIFF(ID7.Date, ID11.Date, Milliseconds)

The result should be some like this:

```
  ID   Date                      Interrupt    Automatic    Interrupttime
    ------------------------------------------------------------------
15   2020-07-06 09:56:35.630        0           1
12   2020-07-06 09:56:32.490        1           0             3,140
11   2020-07-06 09:56:30.073        0           1
 7   2020-07-06 09:56:26.867        1           0             3,206         
 6   2020-07-06 09:56:25.863        0           1
 3   2020-07-06 09:56:19.340        1           0             6,523
```

The difference is the Interrupttime in senconds. The dataset will grow in the future, so I want to create a job for automatically calculation.

In my attempts I fail. I hope you can help me to calculate the Interrupttime.
I'm thankful in advance.

Best regards

Christian

Comment: Edti yur quetison and show the results you want.

Comment: Not sure if LAG() works in your case, partition by "you may need to create a partion from Interrupt+Automatic". like Partition1=Int1Auto0; Partition2=Int0Auto1
https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-window-functions/sql-server-lag-function/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I use the code, I get the following return:

```
ID, Date, Interrupt, Automatik, Startdate, Differenz
1   2020-06-07 09:56:35.630 0   1   NULL    NULL
5   2020-06-07 09:56:30.073 0   1   2020-06-07 09:56:35.630 -5557
10  2020-06-07 09:56:25.863 0   1   2020-06-07 09:56:35.630 -9767
14  2020-06-07 09:56:17.003 0   1   2020-06-07 09:56:35.630 -18627
```

The last column is dependent to date of the first row. The startdate is in each case the same. But if we look in the example, ID 3 is a pair with ID 6 and ID 7 is a pair with ID 11 and so on. In each case there is another start- and enddate.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmmm . . . Use a cumulative max to get the start date for each row.  Then filter down to the end dates and calculate the diff:

```
select t.*, datediff(millisecond, start_date, date)
from (select t.*,
             max(case when interrupt = 1 and automatic = 0 then date end) over (order by id) as start_date
      from t
     ) t
where interrupt = 0 and automatic = 1;
```